# How to sum BigDecimal Field in group of JasperReports report?

Tags: jasper-reports, bigdecimal

I need to do a high precision sum in a footer of *JasperReports*'s report. Usually if you have a Double field you can drag and drop the field in the footer group and a popup window will be show displaying what kind of calculation do you what, sum for example. But if you have a BigDecimal field this popup window does not show.

So how can I sum BigDecimal Field in a (footer) group of report?

Comment: Why you don't use variables? just create a variable and use it in your report...

Answer (score 0):

Just go the manual way.

- Add a variable
- Give it a meaningful name
- Change the type to `java.math.BigDecimal`
- Set the `Calculation` to the type you need, `Sum` in your example
- Add the variable to a text field or add it with drag and drop to the report
- Set your desired `Evaluation time`